# How to create WizardFormPage dynamically in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore

We are using the WizardForm xml control for implementing some sort of backend sitecore wizard. We want to add the controls to the pages (or even create new custom pages) on the fly, dynamically depending on the selection done in the previous page.

What I've already done: we called a parent control of the page control on the page (in ActivePageChanging event) and tried to add a new object of type "WizardDialogBaseXmlControl" there. But no new pages are displayed in the frontend. I still see the same number of pages in the browser's dev. tools that I added at design time in xml. I tried "SheerResponse.Redraw()", but that didn't help either.

My next attempt was to create some pages in the xml file at design time and just populate them with controls, but that doesn't work after the wizard has already loaded. Something like "ControlName.Controls.Add(new ControlName())" only works if it is called in the overridden method "OnLoad()".

This code doesn't work:

```
protected override bool ActivePageChanging(string page, ref string newpage)
        {
            if (newpage.Equals(Consts.PrototypeDetailsPageId))
            {
                if (IsFormItemSelected(out var formItem))
                {
                    PrototypeDetailsPanel0.Controls.Add(new Literal("some text"));
                }
                else
                {
                    SheerResponse.Alert("You must select a form item");
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return base.ActivePageChanging(page, ref newpage);
        }
```

How can I create a working wizard that adds pages and controls at runtime when they depend on changes on previous pages of the same wizard?

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore `WizardForm` relies on the `newpage` parameter to process navigation between steps. So you can prepare alternative versions of wizard steps in advance and set one of them as `newpage` depending on values entered in the previous step. For example, this is how your code can look like:

```
protected override bool ActivePageChanging(string page, ref string newpage)
{
    if (newpage.Equals(Consts.PrototypeDetailsPageId))
    {
        if (IsFormItemSelected(out var formItem))
        {
            newpage = "WizardPageWithAdditionalFields";
        }
        else
        {
            SheerResponse.Alert("You must select a form item");
            return false;
        }
    }

    return base.ActivePageChanging(page, ref newpage);
}
```

I also found it useful that wizard forms can be easily created with [Interactive Dialogs](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/interfaces/interactive-dialogs) from PowerShell Extensions.
Just as an alternative solution, here is an example of how you can display multiple dialogs to navigate users through a number of steps:

```
--Prepare step 1
$options = @{
    "A"="a"
    "B"="b"
}

$props = @{
    Parameters = @(
        @{Name="selectedOption"; Title="Choose an option"; Options=$options}
    )
    Title = "Step 1"
}

--Display step 1
$result = Read-Variable @props

if($result -ne "ok") { exit }

--Step 2
if($selectedOption -eq "Expected value") {
    --Perform additional logic, for example modify @props to include additional steps
    $props = @{
        ...
    }  
}

--Display step 2
$result = Read-Variable @props
```